What does "the Offices" refer to?
From John Le Carré's Smiley's People:
(After an ex-agent Vladimir was shot, Lacon asked Smiley to do the clean-up work.)

“It’s a yes or no, George,” Lacon said. “There’s cleaning up to be done. Explanations to be given to tradesmen, what do I know? Mail. Milk. Friends. Whatever such people have. No one knows the course as you do. No one. The police have promised you a head start. They will not be dilatory but they will observe a certain measured order about things and let routine play its part.” With a nervous bound Lacon approached Smiley’s chair and sat awkwardly on the arm. “George. You were their vicar. Very well, I’m asking you to go and read the Offices. He wanted you, George. Not us. You.”

Does the Offices here refer to some religious text? And if yes, what text exactly?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_hours / https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liturgy_of_the_Hours

"The Offices" refers to the daily services of prayer and worship that a priest of the Church of England is expected to read, and can also refer to the normal ceremonies that they might perform for a parishoner. Lacon refers to Smiley as "their vicar" (a vicar is a priest in charge of a church), presumably meaning the person responsible for their spiritual health, if not the one actually in charge. "Read the Offices" probably means something like "do what is expected of you" or "perform the necessary rituals" or "do the formalities", maybe paperwork that has to be done.

Could the Offices here doesn't mean the real Offices of a church, but a coined espionage term? The "vicar" here is not a real vicar either, after all.

Yes, read the Offices is a stand-in for read the "regulations". Church of England is capitalized...
